# beamer - \pause - Update the previous texts

Tags: beamer, pause

An MWE is given at the end.
I use `beamer` to prepare a presentation.
I use `\pause` to avoid a lot of text on a slide at the first place.
In this MWE, I have `Inputs` and `Outputs`.
When I introudce the inputs, I want to give some more details about it.
So I write `.... for which we will compute f(x) for all....`.

After I use `\pause` and start to introduce the outputs, I want to 
hide the details of the inputs. This means, I want to keep the input
to be just "The sample size $n$", so there is no more '...for which we will...'.

Is this possible, or I have to do it manually?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}

\item The inputs :

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item The sample size $n$, for which we will compute
    $f(x)$ for all $ 1 \leq x \leq n$.
  \end{enumerate}

\end{itemize}

\pause

\begin{itemize}

\item The Outputs :

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item The average $a_m = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{x \leq m} f(x)$ for all $1 \leq m \leq n $.
  \end{enumerate}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{docum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\only<>{}` to do that. Inside `<>` you can e.g. specify the slide number within a `frame`.

`\item The sample size $n$\only<1>{, for which we will compute
    $f(x)$ for all $ 1 \leq x \leq n$.}`

For more examples, check chapter 9 in the [beamer manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)